# What is the eqivalent of pthread_detach(pthread_self()) in std::thread?

Tags: multithreading, self, detach

I know `this_thread::get_id()` lets one find the id, but it is still insufficient to execute `thread::detach()`.

Comment: std::thread::detach() just doesn't need an id.  It is an instance function of the thread class, it already knows what thread it needs to detach from.  So the question doesn't make much sense, post the code you tried to make work so we can see what you are really asking.

Comment: the question is, however, that the thread doesn't know the thread object it is attached to, as is the case of pthread_self()